# Set Choice from Spreadsheet List and "go to section based on answer" with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form, which I will edit using Google Apps Script. One of the questions is multiple choice, with several answer choices that I provide in a list on a spreadsheet.

I'm having trouble to set "go to section based on answer" for each answer choice, to another page/section in the form. For reference, I use  [this script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256409/google-apps-script-google-form-go-to-section-based-on-answer)

This is my modification script :

```
 function editForm() {

    var form          = FormApp.openById('MY FORM ID'); // Form to Edit
    var multipleChoiceQstn  = form.getItemById(1288364781).asMultipleChoiceItem();   // Item Multiple Choice, where Next Question/ Section based from the choice in this Item. 
    var spreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MY SPREADSHEET ID");
    var sheet         = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MY SHEET NAME");
    var choices       = sheet.getRange(7,4,17,1).getValues(); // Range the Choice for Multiple Choice Answer. 
    var questionsId   = sheet.getRange(7,6,17,1).getValues() ; // Range the Question ID, where we want to "go to section based on answer".
       

    for (var k = 0; k < choices.length; k++) { 

    var choice        = choices[k][0];
    var questionId    = questionsId[k][0];
    var sectionQuest  = form.getItemById(questionId).asPageBreakItem(); 

      multipleChoiceQstn.setChoices([multipleChoiceQstn.createChoice(choice,  sectionQuest)])

      } 

      };
```

As a result of Logger, all answer choices and target questions appear, but the final result is only the last answer choice and last target question/ section  on the form.

Any suggestions for improvement? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather use the [`Show questions based on answers`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062) feature of Google Forms on it since it's already been integrated into it and doesn't require the use of scripts. For your question, can you share some example data as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can visualize what you have and what your expected output is?

Comment: Thanks @Saddles , in this case, the choice will dynamic, from the List in spreadsheet, and I want to set it to "go to section based on answer"  with Apps Script, not manually one by one.

Comment: I understand, and please correct me if I'm wrong. For me, I think that the question with the ID `1288364781` is a multiple-choice question, and what you'd like to do is add the `choices` variable to it and have those choices set to a section you created in the form that's also in the spreadsheet and is created as `questionsId` in the script.

Comment: @Saddles , Yes, right.  Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Google Sheets: Set Choices and Sections in Google Forms

You can achieve what you'd like by changing the logic of the code to create the choices first and then setting the choices afterwards.

```
function editForm() {
  var form = FormApp.openById("MY FORM ID");
  var multipleChoiceQstn = form.getItemById(1288364781).asMultipleChoiceItem();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MY SPREADSHEET ID");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MY SHEET NAME");
  var choices = sheet.getRange(7, 4, 17, 1).getValues();
  var questionsId = sheet.getRange(7, 6, 17, 1).getValues();
  var formChoices = [];

  for (var k = 0; k < choices.length; k++) {
    var choice = choices[k][0];
    var questionId = questionsId[k][0];
    var sectionQuest = form.getItemById(questionId).asPageBreakItem();
    formChoices.push(multipleChoiceQstn.createChoice(choice, sectionQuest))
  }
  multipleChoiceQstn.setChoices(formChoices);
};
```

I created an empty array called `formChoices` to be the placeholder for the choices, combined with the `.push()` method to add them, and set the choices afterwards for them to reflect in the form.

The sample sheet looks like this:

[image]

The sample form looks like this:

[image]

#### OUTPUT

[image]

#### REFERENCE

- [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Feel free to clarify if I've misunderstood what your goal is. I'll be happy to help in any way I can!

Comment: Thanks @Saddles. Your script modification work perfect.  As a beginner, I had tried to learn and complete it myself for almost 3 days, and had not succeeded. As usual, on this forum there are always lots of people who are kind enough to help.

Comment: I have another problem,  and I post it here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181119/choices-set-to-a-section-next-section-or-submit-form-in-google-forms
If You can fix it, your help would be greatly appreciated.